# How to append variables to Shell docs without an editor

Tags: linux, shell, variables, terminal, append

I'm wondering if I can have some help here or any links to where I might find the answer.

To start of, I'm not sure if there's a different way to do it, but in Linux, I'm used to append to a file as follows:

```
echo 'echo "text message"' >> test.sh
```

now, I've been doing fine with that. However, whenever I want to do variables is when I'm lost as to how to do it.
I've tried different things:

```
echo var= date >> test.sh
```

which simply give me the date and time without me calling for it:

```
Oct/28/17   1:28pm EST
```

Then I tried this:

```
var= date >> test.sh
```

and,

```
'var= date' >> test.sh
```

and Terminal then says it can't find the command.
Any Idea on the syntax as far as variables go?

Comment: Can you explain (write) what exactly do you want to append (as seen in the file)?

Comment: I want to assign date to a variable:

Comment: echo var= date >> test.sh

Comment: the syntax of it all is what Im looking for. So that once I call it:    echo 'echo " the date and time is date"' >> test.sh       I may be able to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have read your question right;

```
echo 'var=`date`' >> test.sh
```

Single quotes to stop shell expansion.

Comment: Is that the preferred syntax? cuz Ive tried that as well and it doesnt grab onto the default date.

Comment: I tested the code before I posted and it should populate your script with a line that contains "var=`date`". As to preferred syntax, it is clean and simple. (dang - back ticks removed again!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I figured it out on my own. 
Apparently, I got a few concepts mixed up.
When you assign variables on Shell it looks like:

```
var= `date`
```

but I thought on top of that the terminal can't 
distinguish between ticks and single quotes

```
`, '
```

so the syntax is

```
echo 'var=`date`' >> test.sh
```

Comment: If you leave a space after the `=` sign, you'll get an error: `var` will be unset for the environment in this line, then the output of `date` will be run as a command. You want `var=\`date\``, or better, `var=$(date)`.

Comment: Sorry the syntax is actually: echo 'var=`date`' >> test.sh

Comment: Benjamin W. I would used that but I haven't officially learned it in class so I couldnt use it :( anywho, thx for the assist

Comment: They are alternatives to each other, and `$()` has a bunch of advantages over the much older `\`\``, see for example http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082